# spark scala column to counter of column unique values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dictionary, counter

How can I correctly get column values as Map(k->v) where k is unique value and v is occurence count? I do it within groupby.

```
val getMapUDF = udf((arr: Array[Long]) => {arr.groupBy(identity).map{ case (x,y) => x -> y.size}})
    
df
    .withWatermark("time", "30 seconds")
    .groupBy(window(col("time"), "1 minutes").alias("someTime"), col("foo"), col("bar"))
    .agg(count("*").alias("rowCount"), collect_list(col("aaa")).alias("aaaList"))
    .withColumn("qtypes", getMapUDF(col("foobar")))
```

EDIT:
input

```
+-----------+-------------------+
| foo | bar | foobar            |
+-----------+-------------------+
| aaa | a   | [1,1,1,2,3,3]     |
| bbb | b   | [1,2,3,1,2]       |
+-----------+-------------------+
```

expected output

```
+-----------+--------------------+
| foo | bar | foobarMap          |
+-----------+--------------------+
| aaa | a   | [1->3, 2->1, 3->2] |
| bbb | b   | [1->2, 2->2, 3->1] |
+-----------+--------------------+
```

Q: could I use `map_from_arrays` ?

Comment: can you add some sample input and output

Answer (score 0):

Think this is what you are looking for, given an Array arr

```
val arr: Array[Long] = Array(1,1,1,2,3,3)

arr.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
```

Comment: I think it is no different from my approach. how about .view and toMap? Do i need it in your appraoch in scala < 2.13 ?

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite the code? Do you want to optimize performance and get rid of UDFs by using Spark Column transformations instead?

Comment: I operate on streaming dataframe with 100k rows per second. The performance is important to me. I want to return map of column values with unique values counted.

Comment: how can I achieve Map(uniqueValue->valueCount) from column values with spark transformations?

Comment: I can not use another groupBy because StructuredStreaming does not support multiple groupBy and I can not use foreachBatch in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to replace your UDF with only Spark SQL API / Column transformations, this might be what you want

```
    val data = Seq(
      ("aaa","a",Array(1,1,1,2,3,3)),
      ("bbb","b",Array(1,2,3,1,2))
    )
    
    val df = spark.createDataset(data).toDF("foo", "bar", "foobar")

    val res = df.select($"foo",explode_outer($"foobar"))
      .groupBy("foo","col").count()
      .withColumn("mapped",map($"col",$"count"))
      .groupBy("foo")
      .agg(collect_list("mapped"))

    res.show(false)
```

So you will receive this

```
+---+------------------------------+
|foo|collect_list(mapped)          |
+---+------------------------------+
|aaa|[[3 -> 2], [1 -> 3], [2 -> 1]]|
|bbb|[[2 -> 2], [1 -> 2], [3 -> 1]]|
+---+------------------------------+
```

Hope this somehow helps you

Comment: no, I can not do multiple groupBy as explained because I use StructuredStreaming and can not use foreachBatch.

Answer (score 0):

I think something could be done instead of `collect_list` so that you can get what you want without doing 2 `groupBy`. I assume that your input data looks like `df` below.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

df.show
+---+---+---+
|foo|bar|aaa|
+---+---+---+
|aaa|  a|  1|
|aaa|  a|  1|
|aaa|  a|  1|
|aaa|  a|  2|
|aaa|  a|  3|
|aaa|  a|  3|
|bbb|  b|  1|
|bbb|  b|  2|
|bbb|  b|  3|
|bbb|  b|  1|
|bbb|  b|  2|
+---+---+---+

val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "foobarmap",
    struct(
        $"aaa",
        count("aaa").over(Window.partitionBy("foo", "bar", "aaa"))
    )
).groupBy(
    "foo", "bar"
).agg(
    count("*").alias("rowcount"), 
    map_from_entries(collect_set("foobarmap")).alias("foobarmap")
).orderBy("foo")

df2.show(2,0)
+---+---+--------+------------------------+
|foo|bar|rowcount|foobarmap               |
+---+---+--------+------------------------+
|aaa|a  |6       |[2 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 1 -> 3]|
|bbb|b  |5       |[2 -> 2, 3 -> 1, 1 -> 2]|
+---+---+--------+------------------------+
```

To add watermark and group by window, it may be possible to implement your code as below:

```
val df2 = df.withWatermark(
    "time", "30 seconds"
).withColumn(
    "foobarmap",
    struct(
        $"aaa",
        count("aaa").over(Window.partitionBy(window(col("time"), "1 minutes"), "foo", "bar", "aaa"))
    ).alias("foobarmap")
).groupBy(
    window(col("time"), "1 minutes"), "foo", "bar"
).agg(
    count("*").alias("rowcount"), 
    map_from_entries(collect_set("foobarmap")).alias("foobarmap")
).orderBy("foo")
```